# find / | grep to find files containing git but exclude digital

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I use `find / | grep git` to find repositories. Sometimes it finds lots of files which contain digital. 
It seems quite easy to use `find / | grep -vi digital | grep git`, but I believe that there's a chance of ignoring `/home/auser/.../digital/.../gitrepo`.
I also would like to skip these directories:

```
/home/john/C_DRIVE/*
/proc/*
```

Is there a way to perform a search in such a way that a certain match is removed and after that search proceeds?

Answer (score 4):

Since git repositories have a `.git` folder in them, look for those folders:

```
find / -type d -name .git
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would really help, but I need general solution. I need a way to specify a folder or folder patter to skip.

Comment: @user1325696 why?

Comment: git was an example. I often need to find something. When I search it find a lot of stuff which complicates finding what I need. I would like to tweak search to ignore something.

Comment: @user1325696  Can you give us another example ? There's many ways to tweak `find`, but we need to understand what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is two switches, `-not` and `-path`.  The `-not` operator will allow you to ignore a path that matches the patterns provided in `-path` like so:

```
find / -type d -name ".git" -not -path "/home/auser/*/digital/*" -prune
```

Comment: You should use `-prune` to exclude directories